# How to make application runnable on older version of node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mips, babeljs, openwrt

I'd like to be able developing a Node.JS application using the latest features of JS and Node.JS (like Node.JS v8 or even v13), but I need to deploy the app on embedded Linux server with Node.JS **v4** (Omega2, OpenWRT, **MIPS arch**).

Is it possible somehow to build the app and make it runnable on such an old version of Node.JS?
Thank you for your answers, suggestions, and solutions!

Comment: You can use [babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/) transpiler. It will convert the newer features/syntaxes into a backwards compatible version of JavaScript

Comment: I'd be spending my time figuring out how to upgrade the embedded system to a more modern version of node.js.  Half the value of node.js is access to the huge library of open source modules, very few of which are support on node v4 any more.

Answer (score -1):

You can use nvm to have both versions of node in the system and can run both applications in a different node version.

Comment: I'm afraid Node v4 will not execute some ES features, but most importantly a lot of the modules that I need require Node >8